# Node.js Express Stream large video to Client

Tags: node.js, express

I have some really large video files stored in my **Backup Server**
When a client request for the video I am currently downloading the video file from my backup server to my main server and streaming it back to Client. But this approach is not so efficient.

This is the code I am using to download video from my Backup-Server to my Main-Server upon client's request:

```
async function download(videoID){
      return DownloadVideo(videoID).pipe(fs.createWriteStream('video.flv'));
    //DownloadVideo function requests the video from Backup Server.
}

app.get("/video", async (req, res) => {
  await download(req.query.videoID)
  res.setHeader("content-type", "video/flv");
  res.attachment("video.flv");
  fs.createReadStream("./video.flv").pipe(res);
});
```

Instead of downloading the file to my main-Server, I want to serve the file directly to my Client from the backup-server.
How can I do that?

Comment: I think you can just pipe from download to res directly

Comment: so DownloadVideo(id).pipe(res)

Comment: Thank you for the comments. I did that but only the fraction of a video is being played in Client.

Comment: Hi @radeja1769, I am in the same problem as you was. Have you been able to streaming the large videos without downloading them (on the client and server)?